# Outlook of any version from WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, outlook

I have a WPF application wherein the functionality is to open the outlook application on the users machine. The user can have any version of Outlook on his machine. Is there a way to achieve the same?

```
oA = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ol = oA.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder eF = ol.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oM = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oA.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

int iAttachType = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
oM.Attachments.Add(file, iAttachType, 1, "Att");

oM.Subject = "Capacity Information List";
oM.Display();
```

Comment: This question is not related to WPF. This would be better tagged .net or c#.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're intending to interact with Outlook, but this should work if you're just trying to open Outlook:

```
Process.Start(@"outlook.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, add Outlook to your project references (COM tab) in Visual Studio.
Something like the following should work then:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
...
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem msg = app.CreateItem(0);
msg.Subject = "test";
msg.Display(false):
```

Comment: thats the same code, but the requirement is to open outlook on target machine irrespective of the version

Comment: This answer, as well as the OP's code depend on the version of Outlook at is installed.  If you need to manipulate/interact with Outlook you'll have to add all the different COM add-ins for Outlook and use the correct version that's installed on the machine, if that's possible.

Comment: The code will work with any version of Outlook. Just make sure you develop on a machine with the oldest version of Outlook that you are planning to support (e.g. Outlook 2007). Or you can create the interop dll on that machine, and then add a reference to that interop dll on the machine where you actually develop your code. All versions of Outlook are backward compatible.

Comment: The same was achieved using PIA (Office Primary Interop Assemblies). Sample and explanation found at this link. [link](http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2014/02/13/painless-office-interop-using-visual-c-sharp)